# Should this be a concern "The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again."?

Tags: magento2.4.2-p2

Im seeing this error in my logs, I notice it happends on products that dont have an inventory source asigned to them. This is on purpose, as this are old products that we dont sell any more, we only keep them for SEO.

This is the error, i dont think it should be an error.

> main.CRITICAL: The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): The product that was requested doesn't exist. Verify the product and try again. at vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php:311

This is happening on magento 2.4.2-p2

thanks

Comment: If the product exist, then I don't think you should be getting that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue will happen when using custom modules or your own modules (just because we are not testing our code as much as Magento features will have been tested).

For both cases, it seems possible that you add some plugins around the code triggering the issue so that you can improve the error message.

- you could add the sku that is told to be missing for a start
- you could use this new log facility to cross over your SEO listing and validate that the required sku has a 301 redirect setup already
- you could use this new insight to create some search terms synonyms to channel these users to an existing product

Now, wanting to resolve the problem fully can be a waste of time if it means changing the custom modules you have purchased.

Also, robots/crawlers are often the reason for these type of legacy urls so my advice is just to add some quick wins like the above to gain awareness of the problem.

Comment: ok then it should be debug and not critial. I guess it doesnt matter then as it happends with product that dont have an inventory source assignes. Thanks